# ef core 3.0 query with join table from DB and list from memory fails

Tags: entity-framework, join

I wrote simple query, which should find images with hashes already presented in database. So "images" is List from memory and  _context.AdPics is table from DB

```
 var picsThatAlreadyInDb = (from pic in _context.AdPics
                join image in images on pic.ImgHash equals image.ImgHash
                select new {DbPicId=pic.ID, newImage = image}).ToList();
```

I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<AdPic>
    .Join(
        outer: __p_0, 
        inner: pic => pic.ImgHash, 
        outerKeySelector: image => image.ImgHash, 
        innerKeySelector: (pic, image) => new { 
            DbPicId = pic.ID, 
            newImage = image
         })' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.Expand(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at InfraStructure.SaveToDb.Save(ScrapedAd ad, List`1 images) in C:\Users\fjod1\RiderProjects\crawler\InfraStructure\SaveToDb.cs:line 27
   at Tests.SavePicsTest.Test() in C:\Users\fjod1\RiderProjects\crawler\Testing\Tests\SavePicsTest.cs:line 64
```

So is it a bug/feature in ef core 3.0 or I am doing something completely wrong with such query?

Answer (score 2):

Well I rewrote it into 2 parts, first one loads data from db and second one is same linq query which works pretty fine, because it is working with two Lists from memory.

So it looks like it's not possible to do linq join when one list is in memory and another in db.

Answer (score 0):

```
var picsThatAlreadyInDb = (from pic in _context.AdPics.AsEnumerable()
                join image in images on pic.ImgHash equals image.ImgHash
                select new {DbPicId=pic.ID, newImage = image}).ToList();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: agreed with @Ardent Coder.  The addition of "AsEnumerable()" on the context/DB part of the code snippet above fixed the exception referenced in the original post for me.

Comment: but this loads the whole DbSet into the memory 