# How to Use Join in EF Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

The Code Works Fine Until i use Join

```
            //Works Fine
            var ordersNotInvoiced = await APIMiscOrdersDbContext.Order.Where(o => o.InvoiceDate == null).Select(o => o.OrderNumber).ToListAsync();

            //Works Fine
            var latestOrdersVersionAction = await APIMiscOrdersDbContext.OrderVersionAction
                .Where(ova => ordersNotInvoiced.Contains(ova.OrderVersion.OrderNumber))
                .GroupBy(ova => ova.OrderVersion.OrderNumber)
                .Select(ova => new { OrderNumber = ova.Key, ActionDateTime = ova.Max(g => g.ActionDateTime) }).ToListAsync();

            // Unable to Run this With Join
            var processedOrderVersionActions = await APIMiscOrdersDbContext.OrderVersionAction.Join(latestOrdersVersionAction,
                l => new { l1 = l.OrderVersion.OrderNumber, l2 = l.ActionDateTime },
                r => new { l1 = r.OrderNumber, l2 = r.ActionDateTime },
                (l, r) => l).ToListAsync();
```

The Code Runs if i Remove await from the last statement but says "Result Not Computed Yet"
Any Idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: if you use await will it complete at some point? even if it takes a long time? do you get any exceptions?

Comment: what if you use ToList instead of ToListAsync instead to test?

Comment: @sommmen Got this if i Use ToList()


System.InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<OrderVersionAction>
    .Join(
        outer: __p_0, 
        inner: l => new { 
            l1 = l.OrderVersion.OrderNumber, 
            l2 = l.ActionDateTime
         }, 
        outerKeySelector: r => new { 
            l1 = r.OrderNumber, 
            l2 = r.ActionDateTime
         }, 
        innerKeySelector: (l, r) => l)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.

Comment: did you tried to use the linq syntax? i.e. `from ... join ... select ...`

Comment: @Ackdari yes I have translated the same Code in Query syntax but got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running into this:

[ef core 3.0 query with join table from DB and list from memory fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58979239/ef-core-3-0-query-with-join-table-from-db-and-list-from-memory-fails)

You're joining an SQL table with in memory data which is not possible. Either execute the join all in SQL or fetch all data locally and then execute a join.

I.e. I think if you combine `latestOrdersVersionAction` with your join you will likely have better results because it will all be translated to an sql query and will be executed on the server.

Comment: in EF Core 3.0 or above client LINQ queries are no longer evaluated on the client